# Poloniex & websockets

Tags: c++, autobahn, poloniex

**===SIMPLE & SHORT===**

Does anybody have working application that talks with Poloniex through WAMP in these days (January, 2018)?

**===MORE SPECIFIC===**

I used several info sources to make it work using combo: **autobahn-cpp** & **C++**. **Windows 10** OS.
I was able to connect to wss://api.poloniex.com, realm1. Plus I was able to subscribe and get subscription ID. But I never got any events even when everything established.

**===RESEARCH===**

During research in the web I saw a lot of controversial information:

1. Claims, that wss://api2.poloniex.com should be used, and channels names are actually numbers - [How to connect to poloniex.com websocket api using a python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154121/how-to-connect-to-poloniex-com-websocket-api-using-a-python-library)

2. This answer gave me base code, but I am getting anything more than just connections, also by following this answer - wss://api.poloniex.com is correct address - [Connecting to Poloniex Push-API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467593/connecting-to-poloniex-push-api)

3. I saw post (sorry, lost the link), there were comments made that websockets implementation are basically broken on poloniex. They were posted 6 months ago.

**===SPECS===**

1. Windows 10

2. [Autobahn-Cpp](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-cpp)

3. wss://api.poloniex.com:443 ; realm1

4. Different subscriptions: ticker, BTC_ETH, 148, 1002, etc..

5. Source code I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42523645/4179364)

**===WILL HELP AS WELL===**

1. Is there any way to get all valid subscriptions or, probably, those, that have more than 0 subscribers? I mean, does WAMP have a way to do that?
2. Is there any known issues with Autobahn-Cpp and poloniex combo?
3. Is there any simpler way to test WAMP elsewhere to make sure Autobahn isn't a problem? Like any other well documented & supported online projects that accept WAMP websocket communication?

Comment: fwiw, I was receiving correct data from wss://api2.poloniex.com:443 up until about a week ago, and then something broke. Don't have a solution at this time

Comment: The same problem. Seems like Poloniex have some problems with their API on the WSS and HTTPS side too. When I make GET requests, they response with 404 error.

Comment: @onlyvix.blogspot.com thank You for response. I would appreciate a lot, if You would update your answer as soon as your solution become valid again. That would give me a reason to be confident at least about using URL and realm in autobahn-cpp.

Comment: @Mowshon I disagree about HTTPS side. I tried just now their GET request: [try it](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=BTC_NXT&depth=10). Maybe your IP got banned?

Comment: Rest api works for me without problems, just ws broke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that websockets in Poloniex are unstable. Therefore I can stop my attempts make Autobahn-Cpp work with it at least by now and move on.

Answer (score 1):

I can receive the correct tick order book data from wss://api2.poloniex.com use python3
but sometime The channel 1002 may stop sending the new tick info.

Answer (score 1):

> wss://api.poloniex.com:443 ; realm1

This may be the issue as I've been using api2 and here is the code that works, and has been working for the past 2 quarters non-stop. Its in python, but should be easy enough to port to C++.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import websocket
import json

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")
    connection.close()

def on_open(ws):
    print("ONOPEN")
    ws.send(json.dumps({'command':'subscribe','channel':'BTC_ETH'}))

def on_message(ws, message):
    message = json.loads(message)
    print(message)

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api2.poloniex.com/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
ws.on_open = on_open
ws.run_forever()
```

the code is pretty much self-explanatory (You can check all channels/pairs on Poloniex API website), just save it and run in terminal

> python3 fileName.py

should provide You with BTCETH raw stream of orders and trades on console output.

Playing with the message/subscriptions You can then do as You please with it.